# Condicional doble en c

Tags: c

Soy nuevo en C y no sé en qué estoy fallando cuando al tratar de resolver un ejercicio que dice lo siguiente:
Calcular el monto de pago que consiste en la inscripción más la primera mensualidad, de una persona que se inscribe a la alberca olímpica de la Universidad de Guadalajara.  Si la persona es empleado de la universidad se le hará un descuento del 50% de lo contrario se cobrara el pago completo.  Para calcular el pago se debe tomar en cuenta que la inscripción es de $100.00 y la mensualidad es de $150.00.

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){    

    printf ("Elige una opción\n");
    printf ("1.-Soy empleado\n");
    printf ("2.-Otro\n");

    int a;

    printf ("Digite su opción: \n");
    scanf ("%i", &a);

    int inscripcion = 100;
    int mensualidad = 150;  

    if (a == 1){

        int inscripcion = inscripcion/2;
        int mensualidad = mensualidad;
    }

    if  (a == 2){

        int inscripcion = inscripcion;
        int mensualidad = mensualidad;

        printf ("Su inscripción será de: %i\n", inscripcion);
        printf ("Su mensualidad será de: %i\n", mensualidad);   
    }

return 0;
}
```

Cuando selecciono la opción 1 no me arroja ningún dato; y cuando elijo la opción 2 solamente me arroja la mensualidad pero mal.

Comment: ¿Qué significa que te arroja la mensualidad mal? ¿Qué datos entras y que datos esperas ver?

Comment: No me arroja la inscripción con el descuento cuando elijo la opción 1, ya hice unas mejoras.

Comment: ¿Qué significa que no te arroja la inscripción con el descuento cuando eliges la opción 1? ¿Qué datos introduces y qué salida esperas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como ya dice la respuesta de PaperBirdMaster tienes algunos errores:

1.- La respuesta se imprime solo si se cumple la condición a==2. Para arreglarlo mueve los `printf` después de cerrar el corchete de la condición

2.- Cuando entras en una condición, estas poniendo `int` delante de las variables. Con eso lo que estas haciendo es crear una nueva variable llamada inscripcion (o mensualidad) y la variable se destruye al salir de la condición. Para arreglarlo quita los `int` de las variables dentro de las condiciones.

La respuesta anterior es correcta, pero este es tu código con los cambios mínimos para que funcione, que a lo mejor está mas claro:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){    

    printf ("Elige una opción\n");
    printf ("1.-Soy empleado\n");
    printf ("2.-Otro\n");

    int a;

    printf ("Digite su opción: \n");
    scanf ("%i", &a);

    int inscripcion = 100;
    int mensualidad = 150;  

    if (a == 1){

        inscripcion = inscripcion/2;
        mensualidad = mensualidad;
    }

    if  (a == 2){

        inscripcion = inscripcion;
        mensualidad = mensualidad;
    }

    printf ("Su inscripción será de: %i\n", inscripcion);
    printf ("Su mensualidad será de: %i\n", mensualidad);   

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Le agradezco su tiempo, ya me da los resultados esperados. Era algo simple, pero es parte del aprendizaje.

Comment: Si estás satisfecho con la respuesta por favor acéptala, así podemos "cerrar" el tema

Answer (score 2):

> Cuando selecciono la opción 1 no me arroja ningún dato.

Normal, porque no muestras nada en la opción 1, olvidaste los `printf`:

```
if (a == 1) {
    int inscripcion = inscripcion/2;
    int mensualidad = mensualidad;

    printf ("Su inscripción será de: %i\n", inscripcion);
    printf ("Su mensualidad será de: %i\n", mensualidad); 
}
```

Por otro lado, no necesitas copiar los datos de fuera del `if` a unas variables dentro del mismo, puedes usarlas directamente:

```
if (a == 1) {
    printf ("Su inscripción será de: %i\n", inscripcion / 2);
    printf ("Su mensualidad será de: %i\n", mensualidad); 
}
```

En vista de que la única diferencia entre la primera y la segunda opción es dividir la inscripción, tu código puede ser resumido así:

```
int main(){    

    printf ("Elige una opción\n1.-Soy empleado\n2.-Otro\nDigite su opción: \n");

    int a;
    scanf ("%i", &a);

    int inscripcion = 100;
    int mensualidad = 150;  

    if (a == 1){
        inscripcion /= 2;
    }

    printf ("Su inscripción será de: %i\n", inscripcion);
    printf ("Su mensualidad será de: %i\n", mensualidad);   

    return 0;
}
```